# gwt google appengine with hibernate

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, datanucleus

My GWT project is setup with google app engine. Now I want to run the hibernate code in Google app engine.

I have added businesslogic jar files which contains all the business logic with hibernate implemntation.  I placed my businesslogic jar file WEB-INF\lib folder and   added to classpath.  After running the application and when I click login button,it should validate the username and password.this user validation has been implements through hibernate.But it throws the following exception.

```
    Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: No available StoreManager
    found for the datastore URL key "jdbc". Please make sure you have all relevant 
    plugins in the CLASSPATH (e.g datanucleus-rdbms?, datanucleus-db4o?), and consider 
    setting the persistence property "datanucleus.storeManagerType" to the type of store 
    you are using e.g rdbms, db4o
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppEngine is not an RDBMS! It does not run Hibernate. DataNucleus OTOH is a JDO/JPA persistence solution that allows persistence to BigTable (the datastore in GAE/J)

Comment: ok. Thanks. So I will give up that attempt hibernate by using GAE

Comment: Is there any way to execute my code which is already exists in hibernate. That is seperate jar file. I nust need to access the files thats only. If I can expose those services as webservice can I make it run my code?

Comment: This is no longer correct – an [official example for App Engine + Hibernate](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-cloudsql-native-mysql-hibernate-jpa-demo-java) was posted in 2013.